# How to test Laravel PHPUnit Testing for the post method which contains the value from a multiple select input element

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have been running a phpunit test method in Laravel which tests the article creation which require the multiple value selected from the multiple select input element. But when I test it in PHPUnit and run the test it says some kind of type error in the tags value inside the post method. I am not sure what kind of solution can solve this for the laravel to recognize that the tags value.

A snippet from `create-article.blade.php`

```html
<!-- tags -->
<div class="my-2">
    <label for="tags">Tags</label>
    <select multiple size="5"
        class="block w-auto py-1 px-2 my-2 appearance-none border border-sky-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-sky-400"
        name="tags[]" id="tags">
        @foreach ($tags as $tag)
            <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->title }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

##### `ArticleTest.php`

```
public function test_create_article_post(): void
{
    $user = User::factory()->accepted()->create();

    Storage::fake('test');

    $file = UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg')->size(100);

    $tag = Tag::create([
        'title' => 'Health',
        'slug' => Str::slug(random_int(1000000000, 9999999999) . 'Health'),
        'user_id' => $user->id,
    ]);

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)
        ->post(route('admin.dashboard.create-article'), [
            "title" => "Temp Article",
            "meta_description" => "Just a temporary article.",
            "description" => "<p>Just some temporary article.</p>",
            "image" => $file,
            "tags" => "['$tag->id']",
        ]);

    $response->assertStatus(302);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('articles', [
        'title' => 'Temp Article',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: You should change "['$tag->id']" to just [$tag->id]. It now sends ['$tag->id'] as your value. Not an array with $tag->id

Comment: @daveyvdweide post it as an answer as you are 100% correct. Author, you have literally written `"tags" => "['$tag->id']",` when it should be `"tags" => [$tag->id],` or `"tags" => ["$tag->id"],`

Comment: Thank you very much guys it worked after I changed it to [$tag->id]. Can you please post it as an answer, @daveyvdweide?

Comment: @NayAungLin per your request, I have added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
"['$tag->id']"
```

To:

```
[$tag->id]
```

It now sends ['$tag->id'] as your value. Not an array with $tag->id